# jquery multiple selectors with AND OR condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

If I have a table which has 4000 rows

```
<table>
<tr class="a b c d e f g"><td>xxx</td></tr>
<tr class="a c d e f g"><td>xxx</td></tr>
<tr class="d e f g"><td>xxx</td></tr>
<tr class="a d e f g"><td>xxx</td></tr>
.
.
.
.
.
</table>
```

If I want to select rows which
have classes
(a or b or c) and (d or e) and (a or g)

How can I code the selector statement?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  How long does this page take to load?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('.a, .b, .c').filter('.d, .e').filter('.a, .g')
```

Comment: This, but put the most exclusive selector first (filter on smaller set at the start)

Comment: Just do the testing in IE 7,8,9,10.. it works perfectly~ Thanks man~

Answer (score 0):

First off, 4000 rows seems a bit excessive and is going to be slow no matter how you think of it.  If you just want to use JQuery to select all rows based on a number of different class types, just use the multiple selector syntax:

```
$('.a, .b, .c')...
```

This will select all elements with class a, b, or c.  From there you can use the $.filter() function to filter the list further with other class types:

```
$('.a, .b, .c').filter('.d, .e')...
```

This will start by selecting all elements with class a, b, or c, then it will filter out anything that does not contain class d, or e.  You can filter as many times as you want, once you reach your final list, you can iterate through all the results with the $.each() function:

```
$result.each(function() { do stuff... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $('.a,.b,.c').filter(function() {
        var classes = $(this).prop('class').split(' ');
        return (classes.indexOf('d') > 0 || classes.indexOf('e') > 0) && (classes.indexOf('a') > 0 || classes.indexOf('g') > 0)
    });

    items.find('td').css('color', 'red');
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UcYnu/