# jQuery selector with multiple elements including an AND operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How do I add an `AND` operator for different elements to this jQuery selector?

```
$("h1:contains('Elements') && p:contains('Black')").nextAll().find(".button[name='commit']").each(function(i, that){
            $('[name=size] option').filter(function() { 
                return ($(this).text() == 'Small');
            }).prop('selected', true);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(that).click();
            }, 200*i);

        });
```

This function is triggered by a button. I want this function to check if the h1 in the div contains the text Elements and if the p alongside the h1 contains Black. I know how to do an OR operator which is just a single comma, but I'm trying to implement an AND operator.

I could also change this into an if statement, but I have no idea how to make that.

"If the 1st selector and 2nd selector returns true, find the button[name='commit'], execute the filter function and then click."

```
    <div class="item1">
    <h1>Abstract</h1>
    <p>White</p>
    <div id="form">
        <form>
            <input>
            <fieldset>
                <select name="size">

                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input class="button" name="commit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item2">
    <h1>Elements</h1>
    <p>Black</p>
    <div id="form">
        <form>
            <input>
            <fieldset>
                <select name="size">

                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input class="button" name="commit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729677/jquery-multiple-selectors-with-and-or-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment (which might get cleaned up):

> I want this function to check if the `h1` in the `div` contains the text Elements and if the `p` alongside the `h1` contains Black.

Combining that with your first JavaScript block, what you're looking for is:

```
$("h1:contains('Elements') + p:contains('Black')").nextAll("div").find(".button[name='commit']")...
```

Breakdown:

- `$("h1:contains('Elements') + p:contains('Black')")` uses an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`) to only match an `h1` that contains Elements if it's immediately followed by a `p` containing Black.
- `.nextAll("div")` finds all following sibling `div` elements
- `.find(".button[name='commit']")` finds any elements within those divs that have the class `button` and the `name` `commit`.

Live Example (turning the relevant buttons blue after half a second; I added `type="button"` and `value="commit"` to them for the snippet):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("h1:contains('Elements') + p:contains('Black')").nextAll("div").find(".button[name='commit']").css({
    color: "blue",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  });
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="item1">
  <h1>Abstract</h1>
  <p>White</p>
  <div id="form">
    <form>
      <input>
      <fieldset>
        <select name="size">

                </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input class="button" type="button" name="commit" value="commit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item2">
  <h1>Elements</h1>
  <p>Black</p>
  <div id="form">
    <form>
      <input>
      <fieldset>
        <select name="size">

                </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input class="button" type="button" name="commit" value="commit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Your quoted HTML has two elements with `id="form"` in them. `id` values **must** be unique in a document.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i forgot to add the class="button" in the structure.

Comment: @xSketchy0: Now I know the whole structure, I've been able to markedly simplify the answer. :-)

Comment: Yes thank you! This is what I was looking for. Didn't know you needed the whole structure to be able to work it out. Would the adjacent sibling combinator compare to an AND operator? Like does it work the same way as an AND operator in a way?

Comment: Also how would you phrase the selector if the p wasn't immediately followed by a p?

Comment: @xSketchy0: All compound CSS selectors are ANDs. For instance, `h1:contains(...)` is an AND: Any matching element has to be an `h1` **and** contain `...`; `p.bar` is an AND: The element has to be a `p` **and** have the class `bar`. And so on. Combinators are the same. Re the other: If you follow the link above and scroll down slightly, you'll find there's also a "general sibling combinator" (often called the "following sibling combinator"), `~`: `A ~ B` matches `A` if it has a `B` sibling somewhere after it (not necessarily adjacent).

Comment: @xSketchy0: (Whereas [selector groups](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) are ORs.)